# In CSV file each letter has its own column

Tags: python, xml, csv

```
<Fruits>
<Fruit>
    <Family>Citrus</Family>
    <Explanation>They belong to the Citrus.</Explanation>
    <Type>Orange</Type>
    <Type>Lemon</Type>
    <Type>Lime</Type>
    <Type>Grapefruit</Type>
</Fruit>
<Fruit>
    <Family>Pomes</Family>
    <Explanation>it belongs to the Pomes. Pomes are composed of one or more carpels, surrounded by accessory tissue.</Explanation>
    <Type>Apple</Type>
    <Type>Pear</Type>        
</Fruit>
```

I want to extract the Explanation of this XML code above, and assign it to each fruit(Type) next to it in a CSV file. Here is my code below.

```
import os, csv

from xml.etree import ElementTree
file_name = "example.xml"
full_file = os.path.abspath(os.path.join("xml", file_name))
dom = ElementTree.parse(full_file)
Fruit = dom.findall("Fruit")

with open('test.csv','w') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    for f in Fruit:
        Explanation = f.find("Explanation").text
        Types = f.findall("Type")
        for t in Types:
            Type = t.text
            print ("{0}, {1}".format(Type, Explanation))
            a.writerows("{0}, {1}".format(Type, Explanation))
```

For the print statement it appears exactly the way I want it.

```
Orange, They belong to the Citrus family.
Lemon, They belong to the Lemon family.
```

and so on...

However, in the CSV file each letter has its own column. I would like to have the type in the first column in the CSV file and in the second column the Explanation.

```
Column1    Column2
Orange     They belong to the Citrus family.
Lemon      They belong to the Citrus family.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `writerow`, not `writerows`. And you should pass it a list, not a string.

```
a.writerow([Type, Explanation])
```

Answer (score -1):

In my (very limited) experience, I have found that for writing to CSVs, you have to put the desired text for the cells in separate square brackets, for example:

```
a.writerow([Type]+[Explanation])
```

So it should appear in the CSV as:

```
Column 1  Column 2
Type      Explanation
```

Hope this helps :)